# Number of days between 2 dates - MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have 2 dates and I am trying to calculate how many of days are from 1998.

My current code returns the number of days between the dates, not the days from  1998.

Example:

```
salaries.from_date = 1997-06-23
salaries.to_date = 1998-06-23
```

Query:

```
  select datediff("1999-01-01", salaries.from_date)
       , salaries.from_date
       , salaries.to_date 
    from salaries 
   where YEAR(salaries.from_date) = 1998 
      or YEAR(salaries.to_date) = 1998;
```

Comment: So you want to know what day of the year was the 23rd of June?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more. The question is not clear to me.

Comment: question is too confusing; can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that for a given date interval, you want to compute how many days belong to year 1998.

I suggest below logic :

```
DATEDIFF(
   CASE
        WHEN to_date > '1998-12-31' THEN '1998-12-31'
        WHEN to_date < '1998-01-01' THEN '1998-01-01'
        ELSE to_date
   END,
   CASE
        WHEN from_date > '1998-12-31' THEN '1998-12-31'
        WHEN from_date < '1998-01-01' THEN '1998-01-01'
        ELSE from_date
   END
)
```

This could probably be simplified as :

```
DATEDIFF(
     LEAST(GREATEST(to_date, '1998-01-01'), '1998-12-31'),
    LEAST(GREATEST(from_date, '1998-01-01'), '1998-12-31')
)
```